# Error trying to create my first AWS Data Pipeline (Unable to construct an endpoint for ec2 in region None Error????)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to create my first data pipeline using the console and the CLI template. The job contains a single activity, a CLIActivity that I want to start an AMI instance.  But, the job fails with the error:

```
Unable to construct an endpoint for ec2 in region None
```

I'm not sure where to set the region. I have it in the myAWSCLICmd parameter:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids ami-xxxxxxx --region us-east-1
```

But that obviously isn't were it needs setting.  Can someone identify what needs to be set and where?

Answer (score 0):

I hardcoded the command I previously had in the myAWSCLICmd parameter and it worked.